# Why img inside a button with onclick not trigger the script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have a button with onclick. There is an image inside of the button but its not trigger the script.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("rightdrop02").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.rightmenubtn02')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("right_content02");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.rightmenubtn01,
.rightmenubtn02,
.rightmenubtn03,
.rightmenubtn04,
.rightmenubtn05 {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-family: "focim";
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.right_content02,
.right_content03 {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right_content02 a,
.right_content03 a {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #00765a;
}

.right_content02 a,
.right_content03 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.rightmenu01 a:hover,
.rightmenu02 a:hover,
.rightmenu03 a:hover,
.rightmenu04 a:hover,
.rightmenu05 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.right_img button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.right_img button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.right_img img {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 0;
}

.right_img button {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_img">
  <div class="rightmenu02">
    <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="rightmenubtn02">Button<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></button>
    <div id="rightdrop02" class="right_content02">
      <a href="#">Dropdown01</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown02</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown03</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown04</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown05</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown06</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The img is not the original one because its from a private site. Stripped the html so its less complicated but the css is the same. I also know my code is awful, no need to remind me...

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is not working? The dropdown is working in my case

Comment: have you tried adding onClick to your img ?

Comment: Why do you have such a weird onclick logic? Set the onclick to your button instead of window then you can remove the check for the class. Then It should also work with any content inside the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the image, the event target is the image, not the button. You have to fix the condition in order to get that to work:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.rightmenubtn02') && 
    !event.target.matches('.rightmenubtn02 img')) {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/swynmuat/

The condition now checks not only for the button but for the image inside the button as well.